# проблема с telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Мне нужно добавить пользователя телеграмм в определенный канал. Код перед командой, которая непосредственно делает запрос на добавление пользователя в канал, работает. При отправке запроса вылазит исключение, которое говорит, что вы зашли, как бот, а бот не может делать такие запросы. В интернете ответа не нашел.

```html
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChannel ,InputPeerUser,InputUser
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest

channel_name = "channel_name"
api_id = "#######"      #security inf
api_hash = "############################"           #security inf

client = TelegramClient('new_sec', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

chann = client.get_entity(channel_name)
chan = InputPeerChannel(chann.id, chann.access_hash)

user = client.get_entity("username")

client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel=channel_name, users=[user]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    # For normal chats
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import AddChatUserRequest

# Note that ``user_to_add`` is NOT the name of the parameter.
# It's the user you want to add (``user_id=user_to_add``).
await client(AddChatUserRequest(
    chat_id,
    user_to_add,
    fwd_limit=10  # Allow the user to see the 10 last messages
))

# For channels (which includes megagroups)
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest

await client(InviteToChannelRequest(
    channel,
    [users_to_add]
))
```

Comment: Документация https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html